# sql server - Update Data from Another Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

My problem is:

I have 2 tables **Assignment** and **Services**
I am trying to update one column from another table's column's data like that.

```
UPDATE [Services]
SET
      TeamID = (SELECT [AssignedTeam]
                       FROM [Assignment]
                       WHERE [ServiceName] in ([Services].[ServiceName]))
WHERE
    EXISTS (
        SELECT [ServiceName]
        FROM [Assignment])
```

it does not work. can someone help me about that situation please? Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update using `JOIN`.

**Query**

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.[TeamID] = t2.[AssignedTeam]
FROM [Services] t1
JOIN [Assignment] t2
ON t1.[ServiceName] = t2.[ServiceName];
```

Comment: @TashaTaysteeJefferson : Please mark it as answer if you don't mind

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE [Services] SET TeamID = [AssignedTeam] FROM [Assignment] WHERE [Assignment].[ServiceName] = [Services].[ServiceName]
```